# Quickly change font of text on web page using Chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, fonts

When I want to change the font of the text of a web page, I do it as below snapshot using `element inspector` of Chrome.

But it is quite tiring to scroll down the style list to find where the font is define and change it.

It would be more convinient to have a plugin that may have a right click to open and select `change font` then input the font I want.

If you know one(s), please share.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could take it to the extreme and use the [Stylish extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe).

Set a rule such as

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:400,600,600italic,700);
* { font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif; }
```

---

[Google Font Previewer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-font-previewer-for/engndlnldodigdjamndkplafgmkkencc) is a more specific extension that lets you preview fonts in your current tab
[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can try [Code Cola](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lomkpheldlbkkfiifcbfifipaofnmnkn) is an chrome extension  that allows users to edit individual pages inside of a website.you can view the fonts and its styles using it.

else you can try [whatfont](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&sqi=2&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/whatfont/jabopobgcpjmedljpbcaablpmlmfcogm?hl=en&ei=ELgVUpQJhLKsB4fhgBA&usg=AFQjCNEPWsU2IbhdAXfhNrP8_p409Tp8Hw&bvm=bv.51156542,d.bmk) enable it and move cursor over to find the font